# format number if not a whole number show with decimal other wise show whole number

Tags: php

Let's say I have 2 numbers like so

```
1.50
2.00
```

I want to format the number so that

```
1.50 will show as 1.5
2.00 will show as 2
```

Basically if it is not a whole number then show that with ending 0's removed and if it is a whole number to show whole. I was trying `number_format('2.00', 2);` but that of course keeps the decimals. I was hoping there was a easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the number with 1 and it will remove any trailing zeros.

```
$arr = ["1.50","2.00"];

foreach($arr as $v){
   echo $v*1 . PHP_EOL;
}
//1.5
//2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting both strings to floats:

```php
echo (float)'1.50';
// => 1.5
echo (float)'2.00';
// => 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4ArNTkjX0EjLSc/sURT3VDP1EDdGiKmrqCrq6sA48FUGOkZgFTY2/3/DwA)